# Implementation of Share feature in Web

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, share

I am having a functionality of share in Web.

I am having base64 code which I am rendering as image in Web. Beside the Image I have a button on Click of button need to share the image which I am rendering.

My application is a web application. When I open my web application in mobile, when I click on Share button I should be able to share the image in all ways(WhatsApp, mail etc... what ever the sources we have).

```
const handleShareButton = () => {
if (navigator.share) {
  navigator
    .share({
      url: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${props.fullCardImage}`,
    })
  }
};


 <Button  onClick={handleShareButton}>Share</Button>
```

I don't see any documentation available to implement, I see the same features available in react-native. But I don't see such functionalities in web. Can anyone give me any suggestion on this.

Comment: do you mean you want a button on your website built with reactjs to share an image when clicked  (whatssapp ,  mail ...) ?

Comment: I already have a button onclick of button need to share the image, let me share the code i have

Comment: So the coded provide it is not working ? it seems a problem with the provided  url **url: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${props.fullCardImage}`,**

Comment: with the same i can able to render the image in my application

Comment: so what is the problem ???

Comment: not aware, its not working. I doubt in url, base64 will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247577/discussion-between-siva-sai-and-monim).